# Select element in collection satisfying max in Clojure

Tags: clojure

The following expression

```
(reduce (fn [[c x y] [s k d]] (if (< c s) [s k d] [c x y])) [0 0 0] colls)
```

Is for the element `[e, x, y]` in colls such that `e` is the maximum among all in the tuples in colls.

Is there already an idiomatic expression in Clojure for that? I guess that with macro, it should be possible to express it with brevity.

I feel that Python/numpy/panda has some good example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `max-key`:

```
(apply max-key first colls)
```